# Having a hard time deserializing my JSON string into a .NET object using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, json.net

I am absolutely not an expert with JSON.  So, here's the problem.  I have a web service method that accepts a JSON string and I need to convert it into a .NET object.  I am using JSON.NET (Newtonsoft.Json).  I'm pretty sure my JSON string is not formatted correctly- I'm pretty sure I'm missing some brackets somewhere- here is my JSON that I need to convert into a single .NET object:

```
{'Safety Data': {
    {   
        'unsafe': 'YES',
        'Category Name': 'Body Mechanics',
        'Category Data': 'Grip / Force',
        'Safe': 'NO'
    }, 
    {   
        'unsafe': 'YES',
        'Category Name': 'Position of People',
        'Category Data': 'Falling',
        'Safe': 'NO'

    }, 
    {   
        'unsafe': 'YES',
        'Category Name': 'Position of People',
        'Category Data': 'Other',
        'Safe': 'YES'
    }, 
    'Safe Acts Observed': 'APPLE',
    'Unsafe Acts Observed': 'OK',
    'Date': '11 / 11 / 1988',
    'Observer Name': 'Bob',
    'Observer Group': 'TEST',
    'Location / Area / Region': 'Nowhere',
    'Email': 'abc@abc.com'
}
```

Here's my C# code:

[image]

I've tried changing my JSON around all different ways, and I end up getting several different errors.  What I need to know is for starters, if the above JSON is formatted correctly (or not), and secondly, given my JSON structure above, if it's possible to deserialize it into a single .NET object.

Comment: No, your json is not correct (other than invalid chars “ and ”). Try [this site](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Do you really have smart quotes in your json data? -- this is a definite no-go. It appears you do not based on code your code snippet though.

Comment: @GaryWalker LOL no, take a look at my code sample, I replaced them with single quotes.  I modified the code block.

Comment: -1 Stop guessing - this is for your benefit. See http://jsonlint.com/ and http://json.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing 2 things here:

- You need a .NET class which represents the deserialized object (so JSON.net know which class to create). You can use "paste as json"(Edit-> Paste Special --> Paste Json as Classes) to generate it (once your JSOn is correct). You can also use http://json2csharp.com/ to generate it.
- Your json looks strange. I believe, you **are missing array declaration** `[]` when declaring SafetyData. Also, as pointed out by @L.B you can't have spaces in property names. (i.e. use 'SafetyData' instead of 'Safety Data')

  {'SafetyData': [
      {
      'unsafe': 'YES',
      'CategoryName': 'Body Mechanics',
      'CategoryData': 'Grip / Force',
      'Safe': 'NO'
  },

  {
      'unsafe': 'YES',
      'CategoryName': 'Position of People',
      'CategoryData': 'Falling',
      'Safe': 'NO'
  }],

  'SafeActsObserved': 'APPLE',
  'UnsafeActsObserved': 'OK'
  }

Comment: @MikeMarks Just out of curiosity: how do you plan to handle the spaces in json property names? Are you satisfied with the output of `http://json2csharp.com/`

Comment: ahaha, you're right! that makes total sense - spaces need to be removed from property names.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "Safety Data":
    [
        {
            "unsafe": "YES",
            "Category Name": "Body Mechanics",
            "Category Data": "Grip / Force",
            "Safe": "NO"
        },
        {
            "unsafe": "YES",
            "Category Name": "Position of People",
            "Category Data": "Falling",
            "Safe": "NO"
        },
        {
            "unsafe": "YES",
            "Category Name": "Position of People",
            "Category Data": "Other",
            "Safe": "YES"
        }
    ],
    "Safe Acts Observed":"APPLE",
    "Unsafe Acts Observed": "OK",
    "Date": "11 / 11 / 1988",
    "Observer Name": "Bob",
    "Observer Group": "TEST",
    "Location / Area / Region": "Nowhere",
    "Email": "abc@abc.com"
}
```

You need double quotes not single quotes for json, you're missing an array structure to contain the 3 safety data objects, and there are unbalanced brackets in your example

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is still not valid. If you visit [jsoneditoronline.org](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) or [jslint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) you can validate your json by pasting and clicking the validate button.

Once you have valid json, I recommend looking at the linq to json features of json.net if you want to extract data from your server (you don't need to the matching class to deserialize into)